# python selenium chromedriver high CPU usage on parallel execution

Tags: python-3.x, django, selenium, multiprocessing, selenium-chromedriver

I need to run multiple (i.e. 100) scans parallelly using selenium but because of the high CPU usage, my server is getting crushed very quickly. I'd like to know how can I significantly decrease high CPU usage because even if I run 5 scans at a time the CPU usage still hits more than 50%? Should I use another webdriver or can I somehow slow down the scan time but save CPU power(i.e. apply limits)? I've applied some options to decrease the CPU utilization but it didn't help.
Below is the chrome options

```
def get_chrome_options():
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('headless')
  options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
  options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
  options.add_argument("--FontRenderHinting[none]")
  return options
```

I need to create and run a web driver from my web app (Django) so I have to create a new webdriver each time I make an HTTP request and I can't reuse the same webdriver.
Below is the example.

```
def run_scan(request, url):
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.CHROME_DRIVER, options=get_chrome_options())
  driver.get(url)
  print(driver.page_source)
```

Below info describes my current environment

```
Python - 3.9.7
Selenium - 3.141.0
Chromedriver - 93.0.4577.82
OS - alpine linux
```

Comment: Why do you need to run so many concurrently?

Comment: I need to scan multiple web pages simultaneously but I can't use the same web driver as they will be executed from the web app as I mentioned in my question so a new web driver needs to be created for each URL.

Comment: Your example is just returning the source of a page, is that really all you are returning? Can you give more insight as to what you are trying to achieve with this, selenium is not deisgned for what you are suggesting

Comment: Honestly, what do I do with the source is not really related to this question that's why I didn't include the rest of the code ))) but to answer your question I'd say I need the source to retrieve the data I need from there,  but my question is about how to decrease the CPU utilization when I run multiple scans parallelly.... I use Selenium instead of basic HTTP requests is because I need to scrap dynamic content as well.

Comment: Of course what you are doing is related, the easiest way to reduce your CPU usage is to use a solution that doesn’t require a headless browser

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I've added "options.add_argument('headless')" option to my ChromeOptions() but it doesn't help.